# Grabbing key of dictionary in dictionary with highest value

Tags: python, dictionary, max

So I have got the following dictionary (**Python 3**):

```
mydict = {'a' : {'c' : 1}, 'b' : {'c' : 2}}
```

As you see `a` and `b` are similar dictionaries, they have the same keys, however the values of these keys are not always the same.

What I want of this dictionary: the key (`'a'` or `'b'`) which value (=dictionary) contains the key with the highest value compared to the other dictionaries.

I have been looking at the `max` function but no luck so far.

Comment: You mean the highest value for a given key (`'c'`) or for *any* key in the nested dictionaries?

Comment: specifically of `c` yes, I want `key b` yes!

Comment: Are the sub dictionaries guaranteed to always have only one element? Is that key always going to be `'c'`?

Comment: the nested dictionaries contain multiple keys, but I want the highest value of `c`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the key for the nested dictionary with the highest value for the specific key (`'c'`) use:

```
max(mydict, key=lambda k: mydict[k]['c'])
```

or use

```
max(mydict, key=lambda k: mydict[k].get('c', float('-inf')))
```

if not all nested dictionaries have the `'c'` key. The `float('-inf')` return value ensures that those keys are not picked as the maximum.

The `key` function is called for each key from `mydict`, and its return value is used to select which one is the maximum:

```
>>> mydict = {'a' : {'c' : 1}, 'b' : {'c' : 2}}
>>> max(mydict, key=lambda k: mydict[k]['c'])
'b'
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thank you, will be set as answer asap!

Answer (score 4):

`max()` function supports `key` argument to which you can pass a function object (like lambda) and this function would receive each value of the list/iterable you passed to max, and should return the value on which to calculate the max.

Example -

```
>>> mydict = {'a' : {'c' : 1}, 'b' : {'c' : 2}}
>>> max(mydict, key=lambda x: mydict[x]['c'])
'b'
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about passing the functions! Unfortunately Martijn Pieters was first, but I still upvoted your answer!

Comment: @ThomasWagenaar it does not matter who was first it only matters whose answer you think is best

Comment: I understand, but when I wrote that comment the answers were near enough the same (the code was the same)

Comment: @ThomasWagenaar then timing matters :P